# iOS tabBarController is not displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a main tabBarController with some tabs as main controller and each tab contains some objects. Once a view is called, for example, pressing one cell of tableview, tabBar dissapears using,

```
AppsViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:AppsViewController animated:YES];
```

New view contains a new tabBarController but it is not displayed! How to solve it? If not possible, another option would be insert a tabBar (is displayed properly!) instead of tabBarController and then handle its control programmaticaly. How? any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iPhone-TabBar-Application-Tutorial-UITabBar.html >> See this blog post..it may help you..

Comment: thanks but this example is based on tabBarController, not on a single tabBar object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about UITabarController you can't select a controller in a tab that is also a tabbarcontroller. The only way to do it is presenting it modally. In the hig and view controller programmming guide is clearly explained why. The reason is about view controllers hierarchies.

Comment: modal view controller solved it! I appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly speaking i dont use Tab Bars . it gets very complicated in certain conditions to customize it. What i do is that i place some Custom Buttons in place of tabs. and let the designer do the rest. the images of the buttons look exactly like a tab bar in ur app and u can easily customize it the way u want it

i could have shown u the snap shot of my recent app which looks like a tab bar but consists of custom buttons

let me know what u think about it 
Cheers

W

Comment: thank you for your reply but unfortunately I must use a tabBar or tabBarController... However I also use this method on android, I will try to change some code in order to test it...